# CloudKit WHERE NOT IN Predicate

Tags: objective-c, iphone

How I can create a **WHERE NOT IN** condition by using NSPredicates?

I want to fetch all the records those are not already fetched by user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following Code solved my problem.

```
NSMutableArray *lodedRecords = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[lodedRecords addObject:@"ali"];
NSPredicate *notInPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"NOT (firstName  IN %@)",lodedRecords];
CKQuery *query = [[CKQuery alloc] initWithRecordType:recordType
                                           predicate:notInPredicate];
CKQueryOperation *queryOperation = [[CKQueryOperation alloc] initWithQuery:query];
```